# How to use Poedit with smarty templates?

Tags: php, smarty, gettext, poedit

I'm using PoEdit on smarty templates (phtml and tpl files) with the following Poedit configuration for PHP parser :

Extensions:

```
*.php;*.phtml;*.tpl
```

Parser command :

```
xgettext --language=PHP --force-po -o %o %C %K %F
```

If i'm using gettext inside PHP tags `<?php _('test'); ?>` Poedit detect that translation as expected. But i'm using Smarty `{_('test')}` for displaying the translation, Poedit don't detect it.

Is there a way to make Smarty detect { and } characters as PHP tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I got to work with Yii used with Smarty and gettext. but poedit not support the syntax of smarty.

https://github.com/Garefild/PoeditSmarty

And here comes the use of PoeditSmarty allowed Poedit recognize the syntax of Smarty.

```
{t}Text to be localized{/t}
{"Text to be localized"|_} 
{_("Text to be localized")}
```

Very simple to use, PoeditSmarty creates a "pot" file which Poedit know to read.

For example, I have a file "Header.tpl"

```
        <form class="login" method="post" id="login">
        <h2>{__('login')}</h2>
        <div class="wrap">
            <input type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="{__('Username')}" class="form-control" name="username">
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="{__('Password')}" class="form-control" name="password">
            <div class="captcha">
                <img alt="" src="" id="codeImage">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a href="#" id="code" class="forgot">{__('Get a new code')}</a>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="{__('verify Code')}" class="form-control" name="verifyCode">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn login-btn" name="submitLogin">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                {__('Log me in')}
            </button>
            <hr>
            <div class="password">
                <p>{__('Do you not remember your password')} ?</p>
                <a data-toggle="modal" class="forgot">{__('Password Recovery')}</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <h3 class="logo">{__('siteName')}</h3>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I'll run the PoeditSmarty via cmd

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\PoeditSmarty.jar" -o C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\xxx\tempPot.pot -c UTF-8 -k __ -f header.tpl
```

The result of pot file

```
    # Garefild2@gmail.com.
    # Garefild <Garefild2@gmail.com>, 2015-2020.
    #

    msgid ""
    msgstr ""
    "Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
    "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
    "POT-Creation-Date: 2015-12-29 16:47\n"
    "PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
    "Last-Translator: FULL NAME <Garefild2@gmail.com>\n"
    "Language-Team: LANGUAGE <Garefild2@gmail.com>\n"
    "Language: \n"
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

    #: header.tpl:48
    msgid "Password Recovery"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:36
    msgid "Get a new code"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:29
    msgid "Username"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:39
    msgid "verify Code"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:51
    msgid "siteName"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:27
    msgid "login"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:47
    msgid "Do you not remember your password"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:31
    msgid "Password"
    msgstr ""

    #: header.tpl:43
    msgid "Log me in"
    msgstr ""
```

via Poedit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNeMq.png)

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: It does nothing in the ph level, it allows to Poedit know the syntax of Smarty.

And so the possibility of working in conjunction with smarty php and Poedit.

Comment: That is indeed the valid answer, thanks for sharing. I don't understand why it has been downvoted...

Comment: Glad I could help :)
Did you use it? Does it work well?
And a version of java || exe?

Comment: Thank you. It works. I use 3.0.0 version, and it works. But the latest version, 3.1.1 doesn't work.

Comment: umm, explain "doesn't work".
What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to do that. You can change Smarty delimiters but you cannot force Smarty to treat default Smarty delimiters as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I come to is to use Smarty compiled files in the templates_c folder as a source for PoEdit. I just made this little script in order to compile all my views before updating Po files :

```
// ... smarty config here ...

$i = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('./views/')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_file('./views/'.$file) {
            $smarty->fetch('./views/'.$file);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
die('<h2>' . $i . ' templates compiled</h2>');
```

Comment: Or you could use `$smarty->compileAllTemplates()`