# PoEdit 2.4 -- extractor for Smarty templates

Tags: smarty, poedit

I can't get out the strings from `.tpl`, from `.hlp` and from `.js` files. I'm trying to use Poedit 2.4.2 and PoeditSmarty -- I'm not quite sure, if it's necessary... I've tried to follow [How to use Poedit with smarty templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503480/how-to-use-poedit-with-smarty-templates), but nothing happens (mean: noting extracted from `.tpl` files, only from `.php` files.)

In `Poedit` -> `File` -> `Settings` -> `Extractors` I have an item named "Smarty".
In the "Extensions" box there are `‪*.tpl, *.hlp, *.js`, in the command line: `‪"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin\java" -jar "c:\Desktop\PoeditSmarty-master\PoeditSmarty.jar" -o %o -c %C -k %K -f %F`, and in the next three boxes: `%K`, `%F`, `%C`.

In `Catalog` -> `Properties` -> `Paths` page are set the paths of the files (there are more than 100 files in different directories, I would like to translate), and the keywords, witch are marking the strings to translate (`{ts}`) are listed, too.

But if I hit the 'Update from source' button, only the strings from the `.php` files are extracted.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out is the comma between extensions. The field label seems to recommend semicolons, e.g. `*.cpp;*.h`. Perhaps you can try a single extension first to rule this out as a cause.

Other than that,  I can only share our working setup. We use a different extractor, [smarty-gettext](https://github.com/smarty-gettext/smarty-gettext). We have a wiki page for translators describing our [Poedit configuration](https://github.com/TeamDignitas/dignitas/wiki/Localization#translator-notes). Specifically,

- Command to extract translations: `php /path/to/tsmarty2c.php -o %o %F`
- An item in input files list: `%f`

We basically only use `tsmarty2c.php` and `block.t.php` from that package. [Our copies](https://github.com/TeamDignitas/dignitas/tree/master/lib/smarty-plugins) of those files include minor changes suited to our needs, like compressing whitespace to a single space.